# Remove duplicate line in a Google Sheet

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I have a lot of line in a Google sheet, some line is the same.
see pics: https://tof.cx/images/2018/04/15/4cc45aff5aa8f357527731e0bae3a1bc.png

I tried to clean the duplicate line to become like the next screen.
see pics: https://tof.cx/images/2018/04/15/8a16f3bb8dfcc758b649074574fafbfa.png

I used this code in the Script Editor but nothing happen when I run the script.

Is there someone to help me to found the good way.

```
function removeDuplicates() {
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
var newData = new Array();

for(i in data){
  var row = data[i];
  var duplicate = false;
  for(j in newData){
    if(row[0] == newData[j][0] && row[1] == newData[j][1] && row[2] == newData[j][2] && row[3] == newData[j][3] && row[4] == newData[j][4]){
      duplicate = true;
    }
  }
  if(!duplicate){
    newData.push(row);
  }
}

sheet.clearContents();
sheet.getRange(1, 1, newData.length, newData[0].length).setValues(newData);
}
```

THANK YOU

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about these modifications?

#### Modification points :

- Use `getDisplayValues()` instead of `getValues()`.

  - By this, "Date" can be compared as the string which is displayed in the cell on Spreadsheet.
- In the case that `duplicate` is true, values is added to `row`.

  - By this, the duplicated row is added.

#### Modified script :

```
function removeDuplicates() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getDisplayValues(); // Modified
  var newData = new Array();
  data.forEach(function(_, i){ // Modified
    var row = data[i];
    var duplicate = false;
    for(j in newData){
      if(row[0] == newData[j][0] && row[1] == newData[j][1] && row[2] == newData[j][2] && row[3] == newData[j][3] && row[4] == newData[j][4]){
        duplicate = true;
      }
    }
    if(!duplicate){
      newData.push(row);
    } else {
      newData.push(["", "", "", "", "", row[5], row[6]]); // Added
    }
  });
  sheet.clearContents();
  sheet.getRange(1, 1, newData.length, newData[0].length).setValues(newData);
}
```

#### References :

- [getDisplayValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getdisplayvalues)

If this was not what you want, I'm sorry.

Comment: thanks @tanaike it's what I want, thank you so much!